# Python Unicode CSV with newline between quotes

Tags: python, csv, unicode, newline

I'm using unicodecsv to loop through the lines of a csv file in Python.
Al the strings in my CSV file are between quotes but the csv reader still sees the newlines as row delimiters.

Here is my code:

```
with open(path, mode='rU') as f:
    reader = unicodecsv.reader(f, delimiter=b',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, quotechar=b'"', lineterminator="\n")

    for count, row in enumerate(reader):
        if count < row_offset:
            continue
        record = {}
        for col, mapper in enumerate(mappers):
            ...
            ...
```

Here is a sample of a csv line:

```
"test","this line will
continue on the next line","another column",
```

For some reason, the reader will read it as 2 lines instead of one.

**EDIT**

New Example CSV line:

```
628,2012-07-27 01:59:32,000445,MARC,525,"HE547                           ","1",2012-07-27,,,,,,,,"This is an example, this is a test line.
new line but it is in the same csv line, followed by some enters!


",
```

Comment: Is this Python 3 or Python 2? You are using `b''` string literals here.

Comment: Can you at least show us what *is* returned for those two lines? Feel free to futz the contents, but leave initial whitespace and quote characters intact.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The parser returns an out of bounds exception because  there are not enough columns due the newline. This only happens for the rows with an enter in that column. All the other lines are processed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have whitespace after the comma; set `skipinitialspace=True` on the reader to ignore this:

```
reader = unicodecsv.reader(f, delimiter=b',', skipinitialspace=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, quotechar=b'"', lineterminator="\n")
```

Demo with a regular `reader.csv()` object:

```
>>> reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=b',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, quotechar=b'"')
>>> next(reader)
['test', ' "this line will']
>>> f.seek(0)
>>> reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=b',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, quotechar=b'"')
>>> next(reader)
['test', 'this line will\ncontinue on the next line', 'another column', '']
```

Note how without the `skipinitialspace` flag set, the second column starts with `' "...`, so a space and quote. It is not that the newline isn't recognized, but that the *quote* isn't picked up due to the space.

Another possibility is that your input data uses a *different* quoting character. Either way, the `csv.reader()` doesn't recognize your column is quoted. You'll need to look at the `repr()` of the incomplete column to see what characters are contained when returned from the reader, and what quote character (if any) is still present in that value.

However, without accurate sample CSV data, it is hard to say what problem you are actually hitting here.

Comment: It's still the same, I also removed the whitespaces in the question. Sorry for the confusion, my bad.

Comment: @FrederikVoordeckers: Can you give a link to a pastie with *real* data? Because I can reproduce the problem exactly with the spaces there. You'll need to provide some test data that doesn't have spaces but still produces the problem.

Comment: The data is not for public, can't share it since it contains confidential information...

Comment: You'll still need to produce *something* that shows the actual problem; create a sample CSV that when run with your code, shows newlines not being recognized as part of a quoted column. As it stands, I cannot reproduce the problem unless you have quotes that are not regular ASCII quotes or if there is whitespace between the comma and the quote.

Comment: Added a sample of a line that causes trouble. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @FrederikVoordeckers: That sample, as pasted, doesn't produce the problem either. Did that line produce the problem for you with your code?

Comment: @FrederikVoordeckers: What platform are you on? What line-endings did the original have? Can you show me a `print repr(open('testfile', 'rb').read()))` output (so produce a Python string literal with the *binary* contents of a short file that reproduces your problem)?